# Deployment failed in bluemix. "Unable to get organization from Cloud Foundry"

Tags: deployment, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-tools

I am having problems with deploying an app on Bluemix. 
The following error is showing up in the pipeline in the deploy stage:

```
Unable to get organization from Cloud Foundry
```

It was working correctly before and now seems to be looking for organization. However, it can't find one.
[image]

The configuration for the deployment stage can be edited. However, I can only change the "Deployer Type" and "Target" but I cannot edit the "organization" or "space" field.
[image]

Anyone have the idea how this issue can be fixed?

Comment: As a sanity check, have you tried to push an application using command line(CF CLI) targeting Org/Space you are trying to use with DevOps services?

Comment: given that your bluemix account works correctly (it is active, you can see all regions, etc) I would ask 2 things: 
1. how was this repo created? e.g. did you click "Add Git" on bluemix?
2. does this problem affect all your projects or just this one?

Comment: I am having the same problem with DevOps services, a few days ago the deployed worked but now I am getting the same error "Unable to get organization from Cloud Foundry" and in the Organization select I can't see my Bluemix Organization Name. cf push works.